# multiple inline function in jxs got unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<li onClick={e => ({this.props.func1(); this.props.funcB()})}>something</li>
```

Why can't I pass 2 inline function in my click handler in react?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
({ ... })
```

syntax you should return an object with keys and values.
If you just want to trigger two functions, change it to:

```
{ ... }
```

so:

```
<li onClick={e => { this.props.func1(); this.props.funcB() }}>something</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
 onClick={e => ({this.props.func1(); this.props.funcB()})}
```

is a shorthand Arrow function syntax for

```
onClick={e => {return {this.props.func1(); this.props.funcB()} }}
```

Which is an incorrect syntax since the returned object doesn't have keys. However you don't need it, you can simply call multiple function by writing them within `{}` like

```
 onClick={e => {this.props.func1(); this.props.funcB()}}
```